# Using requests-scala in spark but getting error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using the requests-scala library to make an HTTP call out to an external API.
My spark program workflow is like this:

> (JSON_FILE:INPUT) --> (SPARK) --> (HTTP-API) --> (KAFKA:OUTPUT)

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: requests.RequestAuth$Empty$
Serialization stack:
```

Is there something I am missing?

My code for the HTTP call is:

```
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{coalesce, col, count, explode, from_unixtime, get_json_object, lit, struct, sum, to_json, to_timestamp, udf, unix_timestamp, when, window}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import scalaj.http.{Http, HttpOptions}
import org.json4s.Formats
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import requests.Response

object MainFour {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // This is work in progress to make it work with responses.http

    val master = args(0)
    val bootstrap_servers = args(1)
    val shared_shortcode_api = args(2)
    val file_path = args(3)
    val topic = args(4)
    val checkpointLocation = args(5)

    val spark = getSparkSession(master, "spark-project")
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val static = spark.read.json(file_path)
    val df = spark
      .readStream
      .format("json")
      .schema(static.schema)
      .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
      .json(file_path)

    val enriched_data = enrichWithEntityAndWordCount(shared_shortcode_api)(df)
    val final_df = selectFinalColumns(enriched_data)

    writeToKafka(final_df, topic, bootstrap_servers, checkpointLocation)

    spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
  }

  def selectFinalColumns(df: DataFrame) = {
    df.select(
      col("account_id"),
      col("entities"),
      col("word")
    )
  }

  def enrichWithEntityAndWordCount(url: String)(df: DataFrame) = {

    val wordEntityExtracted = udf(useResponsesHttp(sesssh, url))
    val freqToContent = udf(jsonFreqToArray)
    df.withColumn("api", wordEntityExtracted(col("content")))
      .withColumn("entities", freqToContent(get_json_object(col("api"), "$.entities")))
      .withColumn("word", freqToContent(get_json_object(col("api"), "$.words")))
      .drop("api")
  }

  def jsonFreqToArray = (json: String) => {
    implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats

    try {

      val parsed_json = parse(json)
      val test = parsed_json.extract[Map[String, Int]]
      var words = ""

      test foreach {
        case (word, freq) =>
          for (_ <- 1 to freq) {
            words += word + ","
          }
      }
      words.split(",").filter(_.nonEmpty)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        Array("")
      }
    }
  }

  val sesssh = requests.Session()

  def useResponsesHttp(session: requests.Session, url: String): String => String = (content: String) => {
    val response = session.post(url,
      data = ujson.Obj(
        "content" -> content
      ).render(),
      headers = Map(
        "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
        "Charset" -> "UTF-8"
      )
    )
    response.text()
  }

  def writeToKafka(df: DataFrame, topic: String, bootstrapServers: String, checkpointLocation: String) = {

    df.select(to_json(struct("*")) as "value")
      .writeStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
      .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
      .option("topic", topic)
      .start()
  }

  def getSparkSession(master: String, appName: String): SparkSession = {
    SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName(appName)
      .master(master)
      .config("worker.source.jvm.class", "org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource")
      .config("driver.source.jvm.class", "org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource")
      .config("executor.source.jvm.class", "org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource")
      .config("spark.sql.streaming.metricsEnabled", "true")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
      .getOrCreate()
  }
}
```

It is complaining about body. I do pass it to UDF. Can anyone spot something I perhaps missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since part of `sesssh` isn't serializable, it can't be used to define a UDF.

You'll have to use a different `requests.Session()` for every call.

Comment: Ah, I'm not quite sure I follow. Do you mean I move `val sesssh = requests.Session()` inside the function "useResponsesHttp"

Comment: It worked - thanks for pointing that out. I was wondering if there is a way to use 1 `requests.Session()` for ALL calls. It will make my request faster and not having to open a connection/session for each request